# #VBA - Private Sub Worksheet_Change Error: Method 'Hidden' of Object 'Range' Field

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range, worksheet

Spent over 3+ hours trying to trouble shoot this. Any help would be appreciated. Solutions I've tried at the bottom.

PROBLEM:

I'm trying to update the code so that if anyone selects "NA" in cell E58, (there are 3 drop-down options on this cell: Yes/No/NA) it updates the value of cell E60 and E65 as being NA as well, without disrupting current actions. Every solution I've tried results in the code cycling back to the top and failing on the 6th line from the top and/or crashing the file:

```
   Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

**Error message is: Run-Time Error, Method "Hidden" of Object 'Range' field**

Code as follows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)   

If Range("E8").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E8").Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E8").Value = "" Then
    Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

 If Range("E10").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E10").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("E10").Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     ElseIf Range("E10").Value = "" Then
    Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If

If Range("E58").Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True
     
ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "NA" Then
    Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Range("E60").Value = "NA"
ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = False
 ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "" Then
    Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True

End If


 
 If Range("E60").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E60").Value = "NA" Then
    Rows("61:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E60").Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows("62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E60").Value = "" Then
    Rows("61:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If



If Range("E63").Value = "No" Then
    Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "N/A" Then
    Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "Partial" Then
    Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "" Then
    Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
 
 
 If Range("E65").Value = "False" Then
    Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Rows("67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E65").Value = "NA" Then
    Rows("66:67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("E65").Value = "Yes" Then
    Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Rows("67").EntireRow.Hidden = False
ElseIf Range("E65").Value = "" Then
    Rows("66:67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End If
```

*Note: there are similar commands for rows not mentioned but this action is only required here.*

SOLUTIONS TRIED:

1. Tried adding a line to the ELSEIF statement

   ```
     ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "NA" Then
     Range("E60").Value = "NA"
   ```

While this does spit out the NA in E60, the code cycles back to the top and fails on line 6 again.

2. Tried adding a public sub that would do the same as above with a call for this public sub placed in the same place as the Range("E60").Value = "NA" statement but it fails at the same spot and/or crashes the excel.
3. Tried to experiment with Application.EnableEvents = True/False but this causes the ELSEIF statement ( ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "" Then
   Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True) to not function correctly.

Help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I have just tried that and if I add `Application.EnableEvents = False` right after `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and  `Application.EnableEvents = True` before `End Sub`, it works perfectly fine. What happens when you include those two statements? There is always a chance that you will start an infinite loop when using a `Worksheet_Change` event that manipulates cell values in the same sheet.

Comment: If you're changing a value in the sheet during the update event you absolutely must use `Application.EnableEvents = false` to avoid an infinite loop. Is there any code you've not posted here that does change a value on the sheet?

Comment: @MichaelWycisk Ha, beat me by 4 seconds ;)

Comment: @Absinthe Yes :-). But I agree with you that VBAAWARD did not post all the code, the code posted above does not change any cell values (but the question states that cell `E60` and `E65` should be updated). From what I see, hiding/showing rows alone should not trigger a `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: @MichaelWycisk i tried this before but i must have done something wrong - it worked. it seems that was it. i added the application.enableevents line to the top and bottom (false/true) and added in 2 lines of code at the *ELSEIF Range("E58").value = NA then* point and it worked! thanks so much!

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13860894/why-ms-excel-crashes-and-closes-during-worksheet-change-sub-procedure/13861640#13861640)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `Application.EnableEvents = False` right after `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` and  `Application.EnableEvents = True` before `End Sub`.

Since you are trying to change cell values on the same sheet, the `Worksheet_Change` event will trigger itself when you change cell values on the same sheet and thereby lead to an **infinite loop**.

The modified code will look like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Range("E8").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E8").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E8").Value = "" Then
        Rows("9").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Range("E10").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E10").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E10").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E10").Value = "" Then
        Rows("11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Range("E58").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "NA" Then
        Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Range("E60").Value = "NA"
    ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E58").Value = "" Then
        Rows("59").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
 
    If Range("E60").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E60").Value = "NA" Then
        Rows("61:62").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E60").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("62").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("63").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("61").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E60").Value = "" Then
        Rows("61:63").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If

    If Range("E63").Value = "No" Then
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "N/A" Then
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "Partial" Then
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E63").Value = "" Then
        Rows("64").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
 
    If Range("E65").Value = "False" Then
        Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Rows("67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E65").Value = "NA" Then
        Rows("66:67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("E65").Value = "Yes" Then
        Rows("66").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Rows("67").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ElseIf Range("E65").Value = "" Then
        Rows("66:67").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

*Note: I assume that you had some more elements in your code. You write*

> *I'm trying to update the code so that if anyone selects "NA" in cell
> `E58`, (there are 3 drop-down options on this cell: Yes/No/NA) it
> updates the value of cell `E60` and `E65` as being NA as well,...*

*but your code does not update those cells. Just hiding/unhiding rows or columns does not trigger a `Worksheet_Change` event and will therefor not result in an infinite loop.*

Answer (score 1):

Run the code you want only when cells of your choice are changed, not any cell in the worksheet.

For example :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been 
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

    End If
End Sub
```

For this code only shows the message for cells out from `Range("A1:C10")`. In your case, you should run some specific logic when the change occurs in the E58 and exclude the E60 and E65 on the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Example from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/run-macro-cells-change). Give it a read. This should achieve what you want with little effort.

Comment: thanks for sharing your insight! quick question since the above is taken from the microsoft page directly:

how exactly do i apply this to the code i have? i dont need the msgbox. so do i add the IF NOT statement to EACH section of the IF/ELSEIF/END IF statement?

not quite sure how to apply it. thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried to apply this to my code and it crashed the file again. any insight on how to actually apply this would be very much appreciated. thanks.